# Restrict AppEngine (python) NDB to generate 32bit keys only

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I am using Python as development script and NDB.

What is the default algorithm that generate automatic numeric id (key)? Is it safe to assume that the  key value never exceed in an application if the total records in that application are below 32 bit range?

My actual problem is, my client app does not support 64bit integers, and if AppEngine will generate a numeric key bigger than 32bit integer, my client app will behave unexpectedly. One solution is to use string keys. But large part of client is already written and it will be mammoth re-factoring to change the client code.

is it possible to restrict AppEngine to generate a numeric key below than 32 bit value? Thanks

Comment: key and id are two different things in GAE...

Comment: Have you tried SDK 1.7.7?  This may be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

No. All that the documentation says is that the ID is system generated: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#numeric_keys

However, you may be able to use `allocate_ids` to have the system generate some ids for you, and you can decide whether to use those ids. This will work as long as `allocate_ids` eventually returns a small enough value, but that's not guaranteed either.

One way to help (but not guarantee) avoid this is to use entity groups: each entity group has its own set of numeric ids. This isn't a great use of entity groups though, because the write rate to entity groups is limited (1 write / second is the rule of thumb)

The real solution is to bite the bullet, and make your client app capable of handling large integer IDs.